# How to get back mid-way of loop in python

Tags: python, loops

Here is my code:

```
name = []
number = []

CONTACTS = [name,number]

i = True
a = 'yes'
while i == True:
    name.append(input('Please type in the name of the contact: '))
    number.append(input("Please type in the contact number: "))

    a = input('Do you want to add in any other contacts? Yes/No: ')
    if a.lower() == 'yes':
        continue
    elif a.lower() == 'no':
        i == False
    else:
        print("Type in yes/no only.")
        break

j=0;
for item in name:
    print(f'{j+1}.\nName: {name[j]}\nNumber: {number[j]}\n')
    j+=1
```

I wish to get back from this part

```
    else:
        print("Type in yes/no only.")
        break
```

to the part where I take input for a (yes/no option).
If I use `continue` then it will begin from the top of the loop, then what should I do?

Comment: Why don't you make another while loop?